# SQL GROUP BY ( DATEPART(), field1 ) result set to zero nulls

Tags: sql

I want to aggregate counts, grouped by a datepart and column.

For example, a table with 3 columns with each row representing a unique event: id, name, date

I want to select total counts grouped by name and hour, with zeros when there are no events. If I'm only grouping by name, I can join it with a table of every name. With an hour I could do something similar.

How would I handle the case of grouping by both without having a table with a row for every name+hour combination?

Comment: CROSS JOIN a table containing every name with a table containing every hour, then OUTER JOIN that with your data and aggregate.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The following is the mysql solution:

```
create table hours (hour int)

insert hours (hour) values (0), (1) .... (23)

select hour, name, sum(case when name is null then 0 else 1 end) 
from hours left outer join 
event on (hour(event.date) = hours.hour)
group by hour, name
```

the sum(case when name is null then 0 else 1 end) handles the case when there are no events for a particular hour and name.  the count will show as 0. For others each matching row contributes  1 to the sum.

For sql server use datepart(hour, event.date) instead.  The rest should be similar

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cross join` to generate all the rows and then other logic to fill in the values:

```
select h.hour, n.name, count(a.name) as cnt
from (select distinct hour(date) as hour from atable) h cross join
     (select distinct name from atable) n left join
     atable a
     on hour(a.date) = h.hour and a.name = n.name
group by h.hour, n.name;
```